# How do I position innerHTML plain text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Simple question, how do I format the output text of *display.innerHTML* so that I can position it centered within a determined height?

```
var display = document.getElementById("display");
display.innerHTML = "RGB (" + red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + ")";
```

The output will be a text "*RGB(red,green,blue)*".

This is the CSS :

```
#display {
    height: 100px;
    background: #425779;
    transition: background 100ms;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    
    text-align: center;
}
```

Just wanna display it centered vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center an element horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favourite way to center elements within a container in 2020 is using `display: grid` and `place-items: center`

```css
#display {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  background: #425779;
  transition: background 100ms;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">RGB(x, y, z)</div>
```